# Python: how to compare custom class member to builtin type

Tags: python, list, sorting, comparison-operators

New to python so forgive me if this is obvious.
Say I've created a custom `class Foo`, and make a list of Foo() instances mixed with `int`s, for example:

```py
foo_list = [Foo() for _ in range(10)]
for i in range(10):
  foo_list.append(i)
# then the foo_list is mixed with Foo()s and ints
```

How can a `Foo` instance be comparable with an `int`? Basically my target is to make it possible to `sort()` the above list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `__lt__` and `__gt__` methods to the `Foo` class (less than and greater than) that evaluate `Foo` objects as being less than or greater than integers, this is used by `sort` when a key function is not provided

```
class Foo():

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return self._id < other
        elif isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self._id < other._id

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return self._id > other
        elif isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self._id > other._id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a custom function for the python `sort()` function, see [the "key" function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) in the docs for the sorting function.

As an example, if `Foo` has an integer-like field `bar`, you could sort each instance of a `Foo` by the value of its `bar` with this:

```
def custom_key_function(element):
    if isinstance(element, Foo):
        return element.bar
    else:
        return element  # element is just an int

foo_list.sort(key=custom_key_function)
```

Note the use of `isinstance`, which will tell you whether something is an instance of a `Foo`.

I don't know what fields your `Foo` has, but as long as your `custom_key_function` transforms a `Foo` into something that can be compared with an `int` you should be good.